# The reason behind onClick={alert('hi')} being called at render

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, alert

I understand that this is not the right way to make a button show an alert on click.

I would like to understart the logic behind this.
I understand that on click needs to get a reference to a function in order to function as expected.

In the following example, a reference is being made to an arrow function which will be called on click:

`<button onClick={() => alert('hi)}>Click me!</button>`

But what happens **behind the scenes** in this case:

`<button onClick={alert('hi)}>Click me!</button>`

Why is the statement inside onClick being evaluated at render?

Edit: I am using React.

Comment: Are you using a template framework? What are the `{}` for?

Comment: Yes, probably a framework that evaluates the stuff between {} at parse time. Just use plain JavaScript `onclick="alert('hi')"` and the problem will go away. However, if you're really asking "How can I prevent whatever framework I'm using from showing an alert at parse time while using {}", then maybe you should rephrase the question.

Comment: This for your replies. Edited the question. I'm using React.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine you have a method like so:

```
function getString(){

   return "string";
}
```

and then define a textbox:

```
<input type="text" value={getString()}/>
```

You would expect that the textbox would be rendered with a value of "string" not "getString()". This is because what is within the curly braces is evaluated in the render method.

When `{alert('hi)}` is evaluated it runs the method so what is assigned to the onclick event is what is returned by `alert('hi')` (nothing) not the method itself.

Answer (score 2):

In react application, we write html in javascript and not in HTML.

So at the time of rendering, javascript will execute this function: alert('hi')

By using this syntax:

```
 <button onClick={() => alert('hi')}>Click me!</button>
```

we are passing function reference to on click. Inner block of this function will only be executed when this event is called.